# Error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

Olá, pessoal,
Eu estou tentando criar um xml, mas ele me retorna o erro do título, pesquisei no google e tudo o que eu via sobre esse era que faltava o root, porém, acredito que estou usando o root, podem me ajudar?

```
$valorReal = 340.00;
$dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$root = $dom->createElement("AUTORIZACAO");
$total = $dom->createElement("TOTAL", $valorReal);
$root->appendChild($total);
$dom->appendChild($root);

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo "<xmp>" . $dom->saveXML() . "</xmp>";
```

Edit: Outras sugestões de criar um xml também me convém :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, o problema parece ser aquela tag-raiz "xmp" que você concatena por fora do XML... Eu também não entendi o que ela significa.

Testando no Firefox aqui, ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta remover aquela tag estranha `xmp` que o XML fica correto ;-)

Comment: Obrigado, eu tinha visto isso num video gringo